# problems install php in debian

Tags: php, debian, installation

I have been tried install php in debian 9 but not working to me.

I did this command:

```
 sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Error after it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 : Depends: php7.0-cli but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: php7.0-opcache but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.24-11+deb9u3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

(i tried to install this dependencies but i cant, always it depends to another one)

the /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180310$

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20180310$

deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks advance

Comment: Hard to say from that, seems like you have a dependency that relies on libc6 2.24 but the php7 packages rely on libc 2.27.    Are you using a third party repo?

Comment: Please add you `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the content of files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You have a mixed sources Stable + Buster/Sid which cause this problem.

Comment: I edited putting the /etc/apt/sources.list above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've merged in your apt file wheezy and stretch releases of debian. Try removing the last line of your file :

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

and then try an apt-get update command. Then you could try to install php7.

But be aware that if you're starting from an wheezy install, [you must upgrade it to stretch](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) before trying to install php7.0

Comment: Thanks, I removed this row and after it I deleted the all files inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/, so I installed the php, updated and upgraded with success!